# How to configure map in xamarin.forms pcl project?

Tags: c#, android, .net, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I have created one project with xamarin.form PCL.

I have added .....

**xamarin.forms.maps** and other library and **NuGet Package** added according to requirement in all platform (Android, iOS, Window Phone).

I have given all permission and configuration in all platform.

I have successfully show map and run program in window phone but i have an error in android.

Error is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Column
>   Error     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of
>   $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing
>   'java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\lib\dx.jar" --no-strict
>   --dex --output=obj\Debug\android\bin obj\Debug\android\bin\classes "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar"
>   D:\Project\SimplyFood\SimplyFood\SimplyFood.Droid\obj\Debug__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.0.1.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.0.1.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Ads\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Analytics\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.AppIndexing\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.AppInvite\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.AppState\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Base\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Cast\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Drive\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Fitness\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Games\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Gcm\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Identity\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Location\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Maps\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Nearby\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Panorama\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Plus\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.SafetyNet\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Vision\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Wallet\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"
>   "C:\Users\PB
>   DEV\AppData\Local\Xamarin\GooglePlayServices.Wearable\26.0.0\embedded\classes.jar"'   SimplyFood.Droid

**After update all nuget packages i got below error...**

> Unzipping failed. Please download
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r15.zip
>   and extract it to the
>   D:\Project\TestApp\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.22.0.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\22.0.0\content
>   directory.    TestApp.Droid
>
> Unzipping failed. Please download
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_r15.zip
>   and extract it to the
>   D:\Project\TestApp\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.22.0.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\22.0.0\content
>   directory.
>
> Error     Reason:
>   D:\Project\TestApp\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.22.0.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\22.0.0\742021DEBBD30AFFB5B67FB39AB43D94.zip is not a valid zip file TestApp.Droid
>
> Error     Reason:
>   D:\Project\TestApp\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.22.0.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\22.0.0\742021DEBBD30AFFB5B67FB39AB43D94.zip is not a valid zip file TestApp.Droid
>
> Error     Please install package: 'Google Play Services' available in SDK
>   installer. Java library file
>   D:\Project\TestApp\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.22.0.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\22.0.0\embedded\classes.jar
>   doesn't exist.    TestApp.Droid
>
> Error     Please install package: 'Google Play Services' available in SDK
>   installer. Android resource directory
>   D:\Project\TestApp\packages\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.22.0.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid41\22.0.0\embedded./
>   doesn't exist.    TestApp.Droid

**Is there any other way available to integrate map easily in android, iPhone and Window phone using xamarin ?**

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Visual Studio;

Right-click your Droid project, go to the `Android Options` tab, click `Advanced` and set `Java Max Heap Size` to `1G`

If you're using Xamarin Studio it should be something similar.

It has to do with all the Java bindings that are being loaded and it loads up to much memory. With this setting you increase the default memory available.

You can read more about it in the relevant bug in Xamarin from a while back here; https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8137#c14

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible causes.

1. Your emulator has very low memory, you can increase that
2. You may have some large images showing on Android. Android doesn't do well with images, make sure you shrink them to the correct size.

With your new error messages, go to the directory with the issues and delete all the zip files and contents. VS or Xamarin will download them automatically again.

Also update your compile API target to API 23, you can keep the minimum at 15 though.

Comment: ... I have updated all ... Now when i run program in VS Android emulator then i got an one message on screen with "this app won't run without google play services". How to install google play services in VS Android emulator. Already i have tried to download external google play strore.apk and install using adb command "adb install googleplayservices.apk". after install playservices.apk i got continuously pop up message on screen "unfortunately google play services has stopped". I have tried all version of Googleplayservices.apk

Comment: I haven't come across that particular message before. But what about installing http://download.cyanogenmod.org/ on the VS Emulator.